# Consecutive JOIN and aliases: order of execution

Tags: performance, sqlite, full-text-search, query-optimization

I am trying to use FULLTEXT search as a preliminary filter before fetching data from another table. Consecutive JOINs follow to further refine the query and to mix-and-match rows (in reality there are up to 6 JOINs of the main table).

The first "filter" returns the IDs of the rows that are useful, so after joining I have a subset to continue with. My issue is performance, however, and my lack of understanding of how the SQL query is executed in SQLite.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytbl AS t1
JOIN
(SELECT someid
    FROM myftstbl
    WHERE
    myftstbl MATCH 'MATCHME') AS prior
ON
    t1.someid = prior.someid
    AND t1.othercol = 'somevalue'

JOIN mytbl AS t2
ON
    t2.someid = prior.someid
    /* Or is this faster? t2.someid = t1.someid */
```

My thought process for the query above is that first, we retrieve the matched IDs from the `myftstbl` table and use those to JOIN on the main table `t1` to get a sub-selection. Then we again JOIN a duplicate of the main table as `t2`. The part that I am unsure of is which approach would be faster: using the IDs from the matches, or from `t2`?

In other words: when I refer to `t1.someid` inside the second JOIN, does that contain only the `someid`s after the first JOIN (so only those at the intersection of `prior` and those for which `t1.othercol = 'somevalue`) OR does it contain all the original `someid`s of the whole original table?

You can assume that all columns are indexed. In fact, when I use one or the other approach, I find with EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN that different indices are being used for each query. So there must be a difference between the two.

Comment: 1) The subquery is obviously excess. Do not use it, join `myftstbl` instead. 2) SQL tells what to do and do not tell how to do this. The query execution flow may not match the query text. Moreover, the execution plan may be altered by the server after the data statistic changing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not completely understand what you mean. Can you put it in an answer with your improvements to the code?

Comment: *You can assume that all columns are indexed.*  With respect, it's an antipattern to put indexes on every column just for good measure.

Comment: SQL is a *declarative* language. We tell it what we want, not how to get it. In that way it's different from almost every other language encountered by the typical senior software developer.  MySQL and other RDBMS servers have elaborate query-planning modules that figure out how to get what you declare. It's usually pointless to try to outsmart query planning. But, when you do need to outsmart it you start with EXPLAIN and look at the query plan.

Comment: @O.Jones Indeed. Even after applying Akina's suggestion I found that my query was incredibly slow. While inspecting the query plan, I found that the optimizer chose to use an index on othercol rather than on someid. When removing the othercol index, the query is much faster as it now can only use someid (3x faster). Never thought "over indexing" would be an issue!

Comment: Try a compound index.  `ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD INDEX some_other (someid, othercol);` . And, try the reverse compound index: `ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD INDEX other_some (othercol, someid);` One of them may make it even faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be simplified to

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytbl AS t1
JOIN myftstbl USING (someid)         -- or ON t1.someid = myftstbl.someid
JOIN mytbl AS t2 USING (someid)      -- or ON t1.someid = t2.someid
WHERE myftstbl.{???} MATCH 'MATCHME' -- replace {???} with correct column name
  AND t1.othercol = 'somevalue'
```

PS. The query logic is not clear for me, so it is saved as-is.

Comment: Wouldn't this FIRST do the join of all related tables and only THEN do the selection of rows with WHERE? My goal is to restrict t1 based on some of of the fts query and only THEN join, for performance. So I am not entirely sure about how the execution happens here.

Comment: @BramVanroy *Wouldn't this FIRST do the join of all related tables and only THEN do the selection of rows with WHERE?* Formally - yes. Really nobody knows how the server will process this query. The assumption that something will be performed FIRST have no ground.

Comment: *My goal is to restrict t1 based on some of of the fts query and only THEN join* SQL language tells "what" and not tell "in what order". You may fix only tables scanning ordering (using STRAIGHT_JOIN or outer joins - but the latter option may contradict needed logic). *for performance* The situation when such assumption produces slow query is not rare. Use nested subqueries and test.